# how to add a zip file on a database (laravel project)

Tags: laravel

how to add a zip file on a database (laravel project)

I want to add it here

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column name "file" then upload file in server and save file name in database.and then retrieve file using its name.